# JQuery will not work on Safari or Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome, safari

I have created a fiddle with a really slimmed down version of my code.  Even with the slim version I cannot seem to get my JQuery to work in either Safari or Chrome?  Works fine on Firefox..

Take a look here: http://jsfiddle.net/7wAja/

Am I doing something wrong with `jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {});`

I can't figure out why even the click/alert won't work either that is I assumed it was that line?

Any help would be greatly appreciated, Im still a newb when it comes to jQuery or Javascript.

**EDIT:**
My goal is to append the options value to the url, with that said this is what I have but neither this or the fiddle are working for me in chrome or safari and Im not sure if it is something I am doing wrong:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    $("#landing-select option").click(function(){
        window.location.search = $(this).val();

        });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simpilest way I have found is doing it like this

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

    $('#landing-select').change(function () {
        alert($(this).val());
    });

});
```

If you want to append this to the URL, you could do the following

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

    $('#landing-select').change(function () {
        url = window.location.href;
        url += '?'+$(this).val();
        window.location.href = url;
    });

});
```

Answer (score 1):

not sure what you're trying to accomplish, but the option-element doesn't trigger a click event. the following works (mousedown on the select-element)

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $('#landing-select').mousedown(function () {
        alert('event triggered');
    }); 
});
```

Comment: I edited my question to show what I am actually trying to do with it, I just made the fiddle to see if I could event get the alert to trigger but nothing Im doing is seeming to work :(

Answer (score 1):

You need to add multiple to select to fire option click event:

```
<select id="landing-select" class="select" name="items" multiple="multiple">
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of monitoring for clicks, why not just make a `.change()` event?

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
  $('#landing-select').change(function () {
      alert($('#landing-select').val());
  });
});
```

If you really have an event that you only want to fire on specific options, you could always do this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
  $('#landing-select').change(function () {
      if($('#landing-select').val() == "Option 1"){
          alert("Option 1 specific stuff.");
      }
  });
});
```

And an update for your edit:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    $('#landing-select').change(function () {
        window.location.search = $('#landing-select').val();
    });
});
```